# how to Change the Car model in Google earth 3D Driving Simulator?

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I am Trying a modification in already provided Google earth driving simulator :

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/index.html

Where i am trying to replace the provided 3D mini truck with Ambulance file :

The KMZ file i have uploaded is in my dropbox :

which is public .( and i downloaded it from : 
http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=fe0ea451b7322763f0ebaf08776cf07&prevstart=0 )

My code is :

```
 window.google.earth.fetchKml(
      this.ge,
      DDSimulator.MODEL_URL,
      function(obj) {
          me.finishInitUI_(obj, opt_cb);
      });
```

Its tried debugging the script but no result as its not throwing any exception.The simulator is not working at all.

Kindly let me know the probable cause which might be creating this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit the javascript file `simulator.js` it is located here:
http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/simulator.js

So save that file to your machine then open it to edit it.

The line that sets the `MODEL_URL` is

```
DDSimulator.MODEL_URL = 'http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/' +
                        'demos/drive-simulator/smart.kmz';
```

To use another model simply alter the value of the field to point to your file.

```
DDSimulator.MODEL_URL = 'http://www.yourserver.com/yourfile.kmz';
```

Obviously you would then need to save this file, e.g. `my-simulator.js` and point your implementation to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-simulator.js"></script>
```